# How to store an image with React and Laravel using two components?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, file-upload, form-data

I'm building a sign-up form using React and Laravel, and I want to allow users to upload a profile picture. I have two components, one for the sign-up form and another for the home component. I'm using the following code to upload the image in the sign-up component

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input   name="profile_image" placeholder="Profil Picture" type='file' onChange={handleFileChange}/>
</form>
```

code in home component

```
 const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

    function handleFileChange(event) {
      setImage(event.target.files[0]);
     
    }
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', image);

    const signup = ev => {
     
      ev.preventDefault()
      const payload = {
        Name: nameRef.current.value,
        Email: emailRef.current.value,
        password: passwordRef.current.value,
        password_confirmation: password_confirmation.current.value,
        ville_id:ville_ref.current.value,
        profil_picture:formData
        
      }
      console.log(payload);
      AxiosClients.post('/signup', [payload,formData])
      .then(({data}) => {
        
        setcurrentUser(data.user);
        Settoken(data.token);
      })
      
      .catch((err) => {
         const response = err.response;
        if (response && response.status === 422) {
            Seterrors(response.data.errors);
        }
        // console.log(Erors.Name);
       
      })
    
    }
   
    
  const login=(e)=>{
     e.preventDefault();
     const payload={
        email:Emailref.current.value,
        password:PassRef.current.value
     }

     AxiosClients.post('/login', payload)
     .then(({data}) => {
    //    setcurrentUser(data.user);
        //   console.log(data.token);
          Settoken(data.token);        
     })
     
     .catch((err) => {
        const response = err.response;
       if (response && response.status === 422) {
        console.log(response);
        setMessage(response.data.message);
       }
       // console.log(Erors.Name);
      
     })


  }
```

controller

$path = $request->file('image')->store('public/images');

```
/** @var \App\Models\User $student */
$user = User::create([
    'name' => $data['Name'],
    'email' => $data['Email'],
    'ville_id'=>$data['ville_id'],
    'profil'=>$data['profil'],
    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    'profil_picture'=>$path,
]);
```

However, when I try to store the image, I get store a null value. Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue might be related to the way you are appending the `formData` to the payload. In your signup function, you are creating a new `FormData` instance and appending the image state to it. However, you are then passing both the payload and `formData` as an array to the `AxiosClients.post` method. This might be causing an issue with how the data is being sent to the server.

To fix this, you can append the `formData` directly to the payload object, like this:

```
const payload = new FormData();
payload.append('Name', nameRef.current.value);
payload.append('Email', emailRef.current.value);
payload.append('password', passwordRef.current.value);
payload.append('password_confirmation', password_confirmation.current.value);
payload.append('ville_id', ville_ref.current.value);
payload.append('profil_picture', image);
```

Before making this change, check it in the Controller by doing a `dd($request->file('image'))` to verify a before and after.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but unfortunately it does not appear to address the issue at hand in a satisfactory manner.

Comment: After making these changes what is still the problem?

Comment: the profil picture still empty dd($request->file('image'))

Comment: Well, that means you're not doing it right on the frontend side. In the example I gave you above is the correct way to do a file upload to the server.

Comment: Here's an example of what is returned by console.log(image):
File {name: 'cmp-icon3.png', lastModified: 1521250864000, lastModifiedDate: Sat Mar 17 2018 01:41:04 GMT+0000 (UTC), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 5591, …} and after this i try to send the payload to the server side